# VS2015 Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll missing namespace "UITesting"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm using a reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dllin my project.
When compiling the solution that has "using" to: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
I get an error that the namespace does not exist:
"The type or namespace name 'UITestException' could not be found"

In the auto complete I get only the following options: Resources, UnitTesting, Unittesting.Web.

In VS2013- same solution **works perfectly** fine, and containing the following:
UiTest, UiTesting, Resources, UnitTesting, Unittesting.Web.

Any ideas what can be done except for working with VS2013?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a valid reference to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.dll` as the [UITestException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.uitest.extension.uitestexception.aspx) class is in there not `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest`.

Comment: Adding more references solves the problem.. but there are lots of projects, and the same sln compiles in vs 2013. I guess that something has changed between the Visual Studio versions.